# setprecision is not working the way I'm expecting (c++)

Tags: c++

I keep receiving "10", when it should be "10.5" with the setprecision(1). I don't understand why it's happening and wish for some help rn! Thanks! I also linked the error message...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int avg(int a, int b)
{
    int x = (a+b) / 2.0;
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    cout << fixed << setprecision(1) << avg(8, 13) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
spot_the_error_b.cpp: In function 'int main()':
spot_the_error_b.cpp:14:13: error: 'setPrecision' was not declared in this scope
   14 |     cout << setPrecision(1) << avg(8, 13) << endl;
      |
```

Comment: Since your `avg` function returns an `int` value, that's what it's declared as returning, and the return value gets printed, an `int` value, how exactly do you expect to get `.5` from that? VTC as a typo.

Comment: I am confused about the error part. I don't believe the current code has that error.

Comment: If you want `.5` an int variable will not be the correct choice. `int avg(int a, int b)` should be `double avg(int a, int b)` and so does `int x = (a+b) / 2.0;` should be `double x = (a+b) / 2.0;`

Comment: It probably should just be `return (a + b) / 2.0;`

Comment: About the error: We can guess that you use an editor that doesn't save chamges automatically, like VS Code.. So you can modify the code, and then compile the old version. If so, change the editor settings to "Save before compile":

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an `int` in the `avg` function, you should return a `double` so that `setprecision(1)` can work correctly.

```
double avg(int a, int b)
{
    return (a+b) / 2.0;
}
```